# Angular Reactive form formArray can't insert control based on index

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

This is my form:

```
  this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    details: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });
```

I am calling this function to push control

```
 nestedFormGroupDetails(control) {
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        age: ['', [Validators.required]]
      }));

    **// based on scenario, I want to insert new control. ex. occupation
    this.detailsFormArray.insert(0, [...])  // how to add abstract control here**
  }

 get detailsFormArray() {
    return this.addForm.get('details') as FormArray
 }
```

Pls suggest me whether I am doing it right way and also pls advise how can I insert/push new control in specific index, ex- index 0
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can has a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArray of FormGroups (*)

```
//this insert a new FormControl in an Array of FormControls
this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,new FormControl())

//this insert a new FormControl in an Array of FormControls
this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,new FormGroup({
      prop1:new FormControl(),
      prop2:new FormControl(),
   }))
//or in steps
const group=new FormGroup({
   prop1:new FormControl(),
   prop2:new FormControl(),
})
this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,group)
```

Using FormBuilder

```
this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,this.fb.control())

//this insert a new FormControl in an Array of FormControls
this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,this.fb.group({
      prop1:[],
      prop2:[]
   }))
```

(*)

- a FormArray.value of FormControls give you an array of
  string/number,etc, e.g. `[0,1,2]`
- a FormArray.value of FormGroups give you an array of objects,e.g.
  `[{id:1,name:'name1'},{id:2,name:'name2'}]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am trying to use FormBuilder. But when I run it it ngOnInIt() it throws error :  ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'detailsFormArray-> 0 -> occupation'  ` this.detailsFormArray.insert(0,this.formBuilder.group({
        occupation: []
     }))`

Comment: put in your .html form a *ngIf:  `<form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm">..` generally the error is caused at very early Angular because the form is null at first

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With the ngIf directive, the same error is throwing, means it is still the same.